# Create many to many relation with query set of another model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have an email model which will contain loads of questions. For now, I want the email model to automatically add all of the questions when it saves the model.

So far, this is what my question and email models look like:

```py
class Email(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    jobnumber = models.IntegerField()
    developer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="developer")
    questions = models.ManyToManyField('Question', related_name="questions")
    checked_questions = models.ManyToManyField('Question', related_name="checked_questions")
    signed_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.questions = Question.objects.all()
        super(Email, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('checklists:detail', args=[str(self.slug)])

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I thought that this would just work `self.questions = Question.objects.all()` but it didn't so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can call `.questions.add()` on the saved object with `*questions` as argument to do that.

First we will save the object in the db. Then, we pass the the `questions` objects using `*` option to associate all the `questions` with the `email` object.

You can do the following:

```
class Email(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)        
        super(Email, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # save the object first
        question_objs = Question.objects.all() 
        self.questions.add(*question_objs) # add all questions using *
```

From the docs on [`.add()`:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)

> **add(*objs)**
>   Adds the specified model objects to the related object
>   set.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I would like to get only the active questions. I've amended the code above to be `Question.objects.filter(active=True)` but it's still pull out all the questions. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe all the questions were currently active at that moment. Try comparing the values of `Question.objects.filter(active=True).count()` in the shell and in your code.

Comment: Turns out it was working but because my form was looking at the wrong queryset, it shows all the Questions. Thanks for your time, man!